# How not the project tree in Android Studio keeps collapsing when project tab is minimized?

Tags: android, android-studio

Since the latest update of Android Studio, project tree keeps collapsing from this
[image]

to this

[image]

when project tab is minimized and restored again or I think when android studio is minimized with project tab minimized but it's happening quite frequently and navigating node by node to the required file in nested package is quite time eating.

Answer (score 0):

I have the latest update as well and checked for if the problem you are facing is being faced by everyone else! But the problem u r facing is not faced by me personally in my latest update also our entire team don't face the issue.

-The reason y u r facing this issue is because the update to the latest version of Android wasn't completed properly.

-Go back to the previous version and update again.

Comment: Ok. I'll try this and get back to you.

Comment: Which version are you using? Mine is 3.4.1

Comment: mine is 3.4 go for this version as 3.4.1 is not stable still!